# Click event handler in jsplumb is missing "this" object

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsplumb

I use [JSPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/doc/events) to draw lines between div elements. I have added an click event handler, inside my *init* function:

```
init: function() {
    jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {
      // I have the connection object, but not a this context
    });
}
```

This works fine, but I would really like to have a *this* available inside the event handler as well, with the context of *init*.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
init: function() {
    var that = this;
    jsPlumb.bind('click', (function(that) {
        return function (connection, e) {
            // you can see that here
        };
    }(this)));
}
```

Comment: When I try to access "that" from inside the return function, I get an error that it's not defined. I can see the connection object though.

Comment: Are you sure, that 'this' from init function is defined?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
var my_object = {
  value: '234234',
  init: function() {
    var this_object = this;
    jsPlumb.bind('click', function (connection, e) {
      var _my_object = this_object;
      var _jsPlumbInstance = this;
    });
  }
}

$(function() {
  jsPlumb.ready(function() {
    // your code here
    my_object.init();
  });
});
```